# Why does it jump to my else statement immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey I am trying to add a class and an attribute to my nav elements and for some reason my code jumps to the else statement. Appreciate any help what so ever.

This is my Html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Portfolio</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,300,500,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Content Filter -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleC.css"> <!-- Resource style -->
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="pageone">

    <header>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="images/Logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT ME</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
         <h1>Hy, I’m Robert and I am a webdesigner based in Aarhus.</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="2" class="pagetwo">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <main class="cd-main-content">
        <div class="cd-tab-filter-wrapper">
            <div class="cd-tab-filter">
                <ul class="cd-filters">
                    <li class="placeholder">
                        <a data-type="all" href="#0">All</a> <!-- selected option on mobile -->
                    </li> 
                    <li class="filter"><a class="selected" href="#0" data-type="all">All</a></li>
                    <li class="filter" data-filter=".color-1"><a href="#0" data-type="color-1">Constructing Architecture</a></li>
                    <li class="filter" data-filter=".color-2"><a href="#0" data-type="color-2">Photography</a></li>
                    <li class="filter" data-filter=".color-2"><a href="#0" data-type="color-2">Multimedia Design</a></li>
                </ul> <!-- cd-filters -->
            </div> <!-- cd-tab-filter -->
        </div> <!-- cd-tab-filter-wrapper -->

        <section class="cd-gallery">
            <ul>
                <li class="mix color-1 check1 radio2 option3"><img src="img/img-1.jpg" alt="Image 1"></li>
                <li class="mix color-2 check2 radio2 option2"><img src="img/img-2.jpg" alt="Image 2"></li>
                <li class="mix color-1 check3 radio3 option1"><img src="img/img-3.jpg" alt="Image 3"></li>
                <li class="mix color-1 check3 radio2 option4"><img src="img/img-4.jpg" alt="Image 4"></li>
                <li class="mix color-1 check1 radio3 option2"><img src="img/img-5.jpg" alt="Image 5"></li>
                <li class="mix color-2 check2 radio3 option3"><img src="img/img-6.jpg" alt="Image 6"></li>
                <li class="mix color-2 check2 radio2 option1"><img src="img/img-7.jpg" alt="Image 7"></li>
                <li class="mix color-1 check1 radio3 option4"><img src="img/img-8.jpg" alt="Image 8"></li>
                <li class="mix color-2 check1 radio2 option3"><img src="img/img-9.jpg" alt="Image 9"></li>
                <li class="mix color-1 check3 radio2 option4"><img src="img/img-10.jpg" alt="Image 10"></li>
                <li class="mix color-1 check3 radio3 option2"><img src="img/img-11.jpg" alt="Image 11"></li>
                <li class="mix color-2 check1 radio3 option1"><img src="img/img-12.jpg" alt="Image 12"></li>
                <li class="gap"></li>
                <li class="gap"></li>
                <li class="gap"></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="cd-fail-message">No results found</div>
        </section> <!-- cd-gallery -->


    </div>
</div>

<div class="pagethree">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h2 class="text-center about-txt"><a id="3" href="#">About Me</a></h2>
                <img src="images/Profile-image.png" class="img-responsive img-rounded center-block" alt="My Face :)">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p class="text-center about">To tell you a little more about me, I have decided to make this short 
personal description. I love doing many things: design, photography, architecture, coffee
and all of these traits represent me. I thrive in a social environment, loving the interaction between 
co-workers and clients. People say I’m funny and this makes working with me an ease.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="pagefour">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h2>Feel free to contact me at <span>info@freirobert.com</span></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p>You can also find me on social media on the links below</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-behance-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <p class="text-center">©Robert Frei 2016</p>
    </div>
</div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Resource Content Filter -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script> <!-- Resource jQuery -->
 <script src="js/add.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The css to the item required

```
.pagetwo {
    background-color: white;
    background-size: cover;   
}

.darkNav {
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

And my JS which does not work....

```
$(function () {
var header = $('.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar');
var logo = $('#logo');
var hieghtThreshold = $(".pagetwo").offset().top;
var hieghtThreshold_end  = $(".pagetwo").offset().top + $(".pagetwo").height();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= hieghtThreshold && scroll <=  hieghtThreshold_end ) {
        console.log("WORKS!!!!!");
        //logo.attr("src","/images/Logo-black.png");
        //header.addClass("darkNav");
    } else {
        alert("IT BROKE!");
        //logo.attr("src","/images/Logo.png");
        //header.removeClass("darkNav");
    }

});

})
```

Comment: This will execute every time when the window is scrolled. Go to the magic threshold and see that the `WORKS!!!!!` comment comes in the console.

Comment: There's a huge amount of stuff up there that's not remotely relevant to your question. Please simplify dramatically.

Comment: What are the values of `scroll`, `hieghtThreshold`(sic) and `hieghtThreshold_end`(sic) when you hit your function? Try echoing them to the console so you can see.

Comment: @MattBurland sic? What does that mean? `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar: [sic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic). I'm using it so nobody thinks that `hieght` was my typo and not their's.

Comment: Yes it does fire but still does not execute my code :/

Comment: @RidiculousRob as Praveen has already pointed out, `alert` is a *really bad* way to do debugging in Javascript. It blocks what would otherwise be happening. So you start to scroll, up pops your alert and now you can't scroll anymore until you dismiss the alert. Don't do that. Use `console.log` and have your javascript console open (F12 on Chrome).

Comment: @RidiculousRob Change it to `console.log` and then see. Coz `alert` will screw up your JavaScript execution totally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will execute every time when the window is scrolled. Go to the magic threshold and see that the `WORKS!!!!!` comment comes in the console. Replacing `alert()` with `console.log()` will throw nice light on it.

The `$(window).scroll()` fires continuously while scrolling the page. So since you have used `alert()` it keeps firing every time you scroll, and shows you `BROKE!`.

Comment: Agreed, Don't use alerts - work in the console as much as you can

Comment: True that. They are obtrusive. Blocks user operations.